# website design completely messed up

Tags: design

via the word press admin page, my website looks fine. When you load the website, it is missing loads of design features, i.e. header photo has disappeared, font is all wrong. What on earth happened? Please help... I don't have a hosting plan that allows me to empty the cache, unless I pay. Could something else be wrong? All advice will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'd guess you're failing to load the CSS, or loading the wrong CSS, or both. Look in your browser debug console: check the console tab to see if there are any errors there, and look at the network tab to check which CSS files are being loaded in both and compare the content. That should hopefully give you an idea what's gone wrong.

Comment: Assuming your site is your username, on the homepage there are two CSS files `/wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-438.css` and post-2469 that are failing to load. This looks like it's expecting Elementor to have generated a CSS file in your uploads folder and it hasn't. I don't know Elementor, so I'd suggest you try an Elementor forum or an Astra theme forum instead where you're more likely to find someone who knows how this is supposed to work and can help you fix it.

Comment: Somebody else with the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73354528 . I'm not sure putting the CSS inline is the best solution though, and might not work anyway if you can't clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Your homepage is missing two CSS files that should have been generated by Elementor. You can regenerate these from the admin dashboard:

- Elementor, Tools
- Regenerate Files & Data

Here's their FAQ: https://elementor.com/help/regenerate-css-data/. They suggest taking a backup first if that's something you can do.

Comment: thanks so much for your advice - the website seems fine again! thanks a mill!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Go to settings update permalinks
2. As RUP mentioned regenerate elementor files
   Elementor >> Tools >> Regenerate CSS & data and Synchronize template

if the above not working:
Check the website-health in wordpress Tools, you will find what is the cause.

Comment: I did 2) and the website seems fine again! thanks a mill!